# force width from parent element

Tags: html, css

I have a main menu `#navi`. It's items have different width. The submenus should have the same width, as their parents. I made a JsBin to demonstrate it: http://jsbin.com/yusunohage/1

`A very very very long submenu` should not wider then its parent `A longer menu`.

Here is the **HTML**:

```
  <ul id="navi">
    <li class="menu1">Menu </li>
    <li class="menu2">A longer menu 
      <ul class="children">
        <li>A very very very long submenu</li>
        <li>Submenu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu3">Menu item</li>
  </ul>
```

And the **css**

```
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#navi > li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
 ul.children{
   background: gold;


 }

#navi li ul li {
  float:none;
}
```

Comment: widther? What is that?

Comment: Set a width for the .menu2.

Comment: In your jsbin I see nothing wrong but you should **always** add a width to your floated li's.

Comment: You need to wrap your texts in something as well, it will make it easier to controls sizings.

Comment: @dowomenfart please read my question again: "A very very very long submenu should not wider then its parent A longer menu."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEM:**

- Having the parent element limit the children element without fixing the `css` width parameter.

**SOLUTION**

- Setting the child width to 0px for the purpose of measurement the native parent width.
- Setting the child width with parent width after measurement.

jQuery:

```
$('.children li').css('width', 0);
$('.children li').css('width', $('.menu2').width());
```

Solution here : http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/4m5vkkk2/2/

Comment: I cant ad a fixed width to .menu2 since i dont know how width it will be.

Comment: Please mark as solved if the answer satisfy your needs

Answer (score 0):

First set the height for parent elements. Then care about the width of child elements.

Just put this in your css code

```
.menu2{
max-width:140px;
}
```

Here is the Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nwL1hku4/

**Edited**

As you stated above that you don't know about the width of parent element. You may give **max-width** to child elements, to restrict their width.

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/nwL1hku4/1/

Comment: the problem, that the max width of the child is determinated by its parent. But parent's width is dynamic. I'm looking for something like max-width:parent's width

Comment: Autor stated that .menu2 width can not be fixed.

Comment: @user1930254 Actually by giving max-width to parent element means "Your parent menu will not be wider than this width". I bet there must be a limit where you don't want your parent menu to get wider anymore. Just try it and this is your perfect solution according to me. The above answer is an OK solution to your problem.